# Crossplatform Development in Mobile

Tags: android, iphone, windows-phone-7

Need to develop mobile application in cross platform tool like(Phonegap,Titanium,Rhomobile)
Not chosen any tool, before that i need to confirm what are the things i need to take care, if i choose cross platform development.
Application Details:
Application contains sql db data file of 2mb, application will automatically sync with server for new updates, also need to download image from server.

1. is there any problem / limitation if i choose cross platform
   development ?
2. is there any memory/performance related issue?
3. is native UI feeling there?
4. is there any other things we need to  takecare?
5. any security issue ?

Comment: Maybe you can search [Pros and Cons of cross platform development](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/pros-and-cons-of-cross-platform-mobile-app-development-tools/2379)

Comment: second point clear in above mentioned link.  what about other point when we are using HTML5, JS, CCS3?

Answer (score 0):

You can try IBM work lite which has inbuilt Apache Cordova it has features like custom adapters,Security,Push Notification and single source code works on multiple platform..

1. is there any problem / limitation if i choose cross platform development:  ***Its up to the developer***
2. is there any memory/performance related issue:***I've tried developer edition and  the final build was around 20mb!!!***
3. is native UI feeling there?: ***Yes u can (instead of Jquery u can try Sencha Touch 2.2 for smooth transition)***
4. any security issue : ***Targeted for Enterprise so security is good.***

Comment: IBM worklight is Paid framework..open source we trying...what about Phonegap? is above points are ok with phonegap?

Comment: yes....Phonegap is very good as i said try sencha touch with phonegap as its very smooth compared to Jquery+Phonegap.IBM worklight is targeted for enterprise.